# Having problem with Unıty and Hololens 2 communication

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, hololens

I have created a networking project between Unity and Hololens 2. In the project, my goal is to send any data to hololens and when the data is received I want to see a change in the scene. The code for the projects work like this:
-We see 2 cubes in the scene. As the code run, the first cube turns green. Then we have an event (with an action assigned to it)in the code. When the event happens, the same cube turns red. When the action happens, both of the cubes should turn yellow. However, this is the part I get the problem. The action part (ClientDatagramSocket_MessageReceived) of the code doesn’t work.

I am sharing the receiver code, so if anyone can see the problem and help me I would be grateful!

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
#if !UNITY_EDITOR
using Windows.Networking;
using Windows.Networking.Sockets;
#endif

public class CubeControllerUWP : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int listenPort = 5001;

    private Vector3 targetPosition;
    public GameObject cube;
    public GameObject cube2;
    private Material m;

    void Start()
    {
        m = new Material(cube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material);
        m.color = Color.green;
#if !UNITY_EDITOR
        StartClient();
#endif
    }

#if !UNITY_EDITOR
    private async void StartClient()
    {
        m.color = Color.green;
        cube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = m;
        try
        {
            // Create the DatagramSocket and establish a connection to the echo server.
            var clientDatagramSocket = new Windows.Networking.Sockets.DatagramSocket();

            clientDatagramSocket.MessageReceived += ClientDatagramSocket_MessageReceived;
            await clientDatagramSocket.BindServiceNameAsync("12345");
            m.color = Color.red;
            cube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = m;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Windows.Networking.Sockets.SocketErrorStatus webErrorStatus = Windows.Networking.Sockets.SocketError.GetStatus(ex.GetBaseException().HResult);
        }
}
#endif

#if !UNITY_EDITOR
    private async void ClientDatagramSocket_MessageReceived(Windows.Networking.Sockets.DatagramSocket sender, Windows.Networking.Sockets.DatagramSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        m.color = Color.yellow;
        cube2.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = m;
        cube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = m;
        sender.Dispose();

/*        string response;
        using (DataReader dataReader = args.GetDataReader())
        {
            response = dataReader.ReadString(dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength).Trim();
        }
*/
//        await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => this.clientListBox.Items.Add(string.Format("client received the response: \"{0}\"", response)));
//        await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => this.clientListBox.Items.Add("client closed its socket"));


}
#endif

  /*  private Vector3 ParseDataToPosition(string data)
    {
        string[] parts = data.Split(',');
        float x = float.Parse(parts[0]);
        float y = float.Parse(parts[1]);
        float z = float.Parse(parts[2]);

        return new Vector3(x, y, z);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = targetPosition;
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
 //       udpClient.Close();
    }
  */
}
```

As I worked the code on Hololens I only see the part where the cube turns red. However I don't get any errors which may cause the malfunction.

I need help to see where might the problem is.

Comment: is it possible your socket callback arrives on a different thread (most probably yes) => Most of the Unity API is only allowed to be called on the Unit main thread -> you will need to dispatch the received actions and handle them in the Unity main thread (aka e.g. `Update` routine) .. see e.g. [`UnityMainThreadDispatcher`](https://github.com/PimDeWitte/UnityMainThreadDispatcher)

Comment: Btw there is no need to every time assign the `cube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = m;` - once you got it and assigned it the first time you can reuse the same material directly which already **is** assigned to the renderer

Comment: @derHugo thank you for your reply. I read about the threading but it felt too comlicated for me (I am begginer with all of these :) ) Might there any other possible problem to this? I can share the whole project scripts.

Comment: No not really ... I would simply assume the `clientDatagramSocket` **is** using threading/async code if you want or not .. so you will have to adapt to it and handle the result accordingly ... the linked `UnityMainThreadDispatcher` is pretty straight forward to use .. you just have to make sure that anything touching the Unity API (`GetComponent` etc) happens on the Unity main thread